# How to Joomla login form integrate in html site

Tags: html, authentication, joomla, integrate

I  create website in html and also develop a chatting site in joomsocial community using joomla in same domain.but i dnt no how to integrate  joomsocial login form in html page.Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a form with the same elements, e.g. username and password, then post that form to the joomsocial login location. You can find this url by looking at the post action of the actual joomsocial form. You might have issues with the validation token in Joomla though.

Comment: ya i integrate joom login in html.i login the form in html and go to my joomsocial profile.Next time i login the login Invalid Token error occur and i clear the cache and login the form and go to joomsocial login.

Comment: Only way to get around this is to integrate your form into Joomla by making a plugin/module so that it can generate a token using: JHTML::_( 'form.token' );

Comment: above comment from @martin is answer for your question. If you want to do it outside the joomla you would have to recreate joomla form token and that would be very hard and painful.